# Codeigniter 2.2 - Active Record update with left join and multiple where clauses

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have the following SQL:

```
UPDATE msh_leads ml
LEFT JOIN msh_leads_disposition_log dl
ON ml.id = dl.lead_id
SET ml.assigned_to = null
WHERE ((dl.disposition_id != 6 AND dl.disposition_id != 3) OR (dl.disposition_id IS NULL))
AND (ml.assigned_to = ? AND ml.decline = 0 AND ml.subcategory_id = ?)
```

There is a bit of logic in creating this (some of the where's come and go depending on certain situations) so I was hoping to recreate this in Codeigniter (2.2) Active Record. Im not sure how to add a join to an update or how to add multiple complex where statements to an update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This'll help you. Try this.

> Note: you need to place your values over **?** else it'll throw an **error 1064**

```
$this->db->set('ml.assigned_to', 'null');
$this->db->where('ml.assigned_to = ?');
$this->db->where('((dl.disposition_id != 6 AND dl.disposition_id != 3) OR (dl.disposition_id IS NULL))');
$this->db->where('ml.decline = 0');
$this->db->where('ml.subcategory_id = ?');
$this->db->update('msh_leads ml join msh_leads_disposition_log dl on ml.id = dl.lead_id');
```

Comment: Yep you can put join within update method. Glad to help.